# Eliminate Duplicates in Concatenated String

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a working solution for concatenating multiple records into one field, however I would like to eliminate the duplicates from the concatenated field, as well as order the values by another field.

Here is what I have:

```
CREATE VIEW vwImageDescriptions AS
    SELECT i.ItemId, STUFF(ImageDescriptions.line,1,2,'') AS ImageDescriptions
    FROM InventoryItems i
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT DISTINCT CAST((select CASE When p.Description = '' or p.Description is null Then '' Else '; ' + p.Description END
        FROM Photos p
        WHERE p.ItemId = i.ItemId
        ORDER BY p.Sequence
        FOR XML PATH('')) AS nvarchar(max)) line
    ) ImageDescriptions
go

select i.ItemName, id.ImageDescriptions
FROM InventoryItems i join vwImageDescriptions id on i.ItemId = id.ItemId
where id.ImageDescriptions like '%pla%'
```

This is my result:
[image]

What I want is to not have duplicated image descriptions so, for instance, I want to only see "My image" once in each row that it occurs, and not twice. As you see, I used DISTINCT in my code but that doesn't seem to be working.

Here is very simplified DDL to see the problem:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [InventoryItems]
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Photos
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InventoryItems](
    [ItemId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ItemName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Photos](
    [ItemId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](175) NULL,
    [Sequence] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO [InventoryItems]([ItemId],[ItemName]) VALUES(311,'11" Round Vegetable Bowl');
INSERT INTO [InventoryItems]([ItemId],[ItemName]) VALUES(312,'13" Oval Serving Platter');
INSERT INTO [InventoryItems]([ItemId],[ItemName]) VALUES(313,'19" Oval Serving Platter');
INSERT INTO [InventoryItems]([ItemId],[ItemName]) VALUES(314,'Creamer');
INSERT INTO [InventoryItems]([ItemId],[ItemName]) VALUES(315,'Gravy Boat with Attached Underplate');
INSERT INTO [InventoryItems]([ItemId],[ItemName]) VALUES(317,'Round Butter Dish and Lid');
INSERT INTO [InventoryItems]([ItemId],[ItemName]) VALUES(318,'Sugar Bowl and Lid');
INSERT INTO [InventoryItems]([ItemId],[ItemName]) VALUES(319,'Vegetable Server Bowl and Lid');

INSERT INTO [Photos]([ItemId],[Description],[Sequence])VALUES(311,'',1)
INSERT INTO [Photos]([ItemId],[Description],[Sequence])VALUES(312,'Replacements.com image',1)
INSERT INTO [Photos]([ItemId],[Description],[Sequence])VALUES(313,'Replacements.com image',1)
INSERT INTO [Photos]([ItemId],[Description],[Sequence])VALUES(313,'Outer platter is the 19"',2)
INSERT INTO [Photos]([ItemId],[Description],[Sequence])VALUES(313,'Outer platter is the 19"',3)
INSERT INTO [Photos]([ItemId],[Description],[Sequence])VALUES(313,'Outer platter is the 19"',4)
INSERT INTO [Photos]([ItemId],[Description],[Sequence])VALUES(313,'Another image',5)
INSERT INTO [Photos]([ItemId],[Description],[Sequence])VALUES(314,'Replacements.com image',1)
INSERT INTO [Photos]([ItemId],[Description],[Sequence])VALUES(315,'From replacements.com',1)
INSERT INTO [Photos]([ItemId],[Description],[Sequence])VALUES(315,'My image',2)
INSERT INTO [Photos]([ItemId],[Description],[Sequence])VALUES(315,'My image',3)
INSERT INTO [Photos]([ItemId],[Description],[Sequence])VALUES(315,'My image',4)
INSERT INTO [Photos]([ItemId],[Description],[Sequence])VALUES(316,'My image',1)
INSERT INTO [Photos]([ItemId],[Description],[Sequence])VALUES(316,'My image',2)
INSERT INTO [Photos]([ItemId],[Description],[Sequence])VALUES(316,'From replacements.com',3)
```

Comment: The biggest help would be if you can post table definitions and sample data. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Edited to add the table definitions and sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can be simplified a bit. As I understand the desired results this should produce what you are looking for. Many thanks for the tables and sample data.

```
select i.ItemId
    , ImageDescriptions = isnull(STUFF((select ',' + isnull(p.Description, '')
            from Photos p
            where p.ItemId = i.ItemId
            group by isnull(p.Description, '')
            order by min(p.Sequence)
            for xml path('')), 1, 1, ''), '')
FROM InventoryItems i
group by i.ItemId
```

--EDIT--

Like I said the CROSS APPLY is a layer of complexity not needed here. But this should do the same thing.

```
select i.ItemId
    , ImageDescriptions = isnull(x.asdf, '')
FROM InventoryItems i
cross apply
(
    select asdf = STUFF((select ',' + isnull(p.Description, '')
            from Photos p
            where p.ItemId = i.ItemId
            group by isnull(p.Description, '')
            order by min(p.Sequence)
            for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
) x
```

Comment: The only problem is that it's not ordering the photo descriptions by the Sequence number. This is ordering them alphabetically.

Comment: Gotcha, not a problem. Just order by p.Sequence. But since this is an aggregate you have to tell it "which" value to order by.

Comment: You could use cross apply but seems to add a layer of complexity that isn't really needed.

Comment: I never could get it to work with cross apply. If you can would you post it here, just for my education? Thanks.

Comment: Ok. I got it. So you don't need the DISTINCT keyword because you are using GROUP By instead, which then let's you use the ORDER BY, which I couldn't use previously because I was using DISTINCT. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I usually write like below:

```
CREATE VIEW vwImageDescriptions AS
SELECT i.ItemId, STUFF(ImageDescriptions.line,1,1,'') AS ImageDescriptions
FROM InventoryItems i
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT DISTINCT  '; ' + ISNULL(p.Description,'')
    FROM Photos p
    WHERE p.ItemId = i.ItemId
    ORDER BY p.Sequence
    FOR XML PATH('')
) ImageDescriptions(line)
```

GO

Comment: I get the following error: ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified. So I added the p.Sequence to the select list and still get the same error.

Comment: Also, I need to check for both empty strings and nulls, that's why I used the CASE statement Either way, I still get duplicates, which is the issue in my original question.